# How to make a shell script to move files to individual folders based on the filename?

Tags: bash, scripts

I want to automate moving TV show episode files into individual directories for each episode.

Essentially, in the folder I want to run the script in, I have a list of files. For example: `tvshow.2009.S01E01.episodename1.mkv`,
`tvshow.2009.S01E02.episodename2.mkv`, `tvshow.2009.S01E03.episodename3.mkv`, ect.
and empty directories in the format `E01`, `E02`, `E03`, ect.

I have been moving the files manually at this point with the help of <kbd>Tab</kbd> autocompletion at the command line. Essentially I am typing:

```
mv t
```

and then hitting the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to autocomplete out to

```
mv tv.show.2009.S01E0
```

then type `1` and <kbd>Tab</kbd> again to get to

```
mv tv.show.2009.S01E01.episodename1.mkv
```

then I type the correct folder to get to

```
mv tv.show.2009.S01E01.episodename1.mkv E01/
```

and then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to complete the command. I have to repeat the steps for as many episodes as I have in the original directory, and given the fact I am essentially repeating the same steps and just iterating the episode number, it seems like a perfect use of a for loop in a script.

The issue is that the files are not always in the same format, and will obviously have different names depending on the show. What is constant though is that `S##E##` will **always** appear in the filename and I only need to use the `E##` to identify the correct file and move it into the folder that already exists and **exactly matches** the `E##` from the file.

I am an experienced programmer, but have not worked with shell scripts yet. My thought is to maybe iterate through all the existing `E##` folders, look for a file that contains that `E##` sequence, and then move that file into the folder. Unfortunately I am not sure the correct approach in doing this with a script that I can run on the command line.

Would anyone have a suggested plan of approach or be able to point me towards a resource I could refer to for help?

Comment: So the episodes are already in the show's folder, is that correct?

Comment: @guillermochamorro yes, all the show files and corresponding empty "E##" folders are in the same directory and the script will be run from inside that directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Here is the solution I came up with thanks to the other answers given

```sh
#!/bin/bash

for f in *.mkv *.mp4 *.wmv; do
        if [ -f "$f" ] # does file exist?
        then
                dir=$(echo "$f" | grep -o "E[0-9][0-9]" | head -1) # extract first E## from filename
                if [ "$dir" ] # check if string found
                then
                        mkdir -p "$dir"  # create dir
                        mv "$f" "$dir"     # move file into new dir
                else
                        echo "INCORRECT FILE FORMAT: \""$f"\"" # print error if file format is unexpected
                fi
        fi
done
```

I had to add some error checking to catch any files that are incorrectly formatted and for double episode files where the filename has two matching E## strings (for example `tvshow.S01E20E21.mkv`). For double episode files it will create a directory for the first episode number only and move the file to there. Note that this script will make the `E##` directories as well since it makes it easier to have one script do it all.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are trying to just copy all E01's into an E01 folder, E02's into an E02 folder etc etc if this is the case a bash script like this should work

```
#!/bin/bash

cd $(dirname $0)

for orig_filename in ./mkvfiles/*.mkv; do
    dirname="$(dirname $orig_filename)"
    filename=${orig_filename##*/}
    series=${filename%.*}
    episode=${orig_filename}

    [[ $episode =~ [eE][0-9][0-9] ]]
    epi="${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
    if [ -n "$epi" ]; then
        echo ${epi^^}
        [ ! -d ${epi^^} ] && mkdir -p ${epi^^} || :
        /bin/cp $orig_filename ${epi^^}/$filename
    fi

done
```

The script just iterates all the files, filtering for the Exx (where xx is number) and creates/copies the file to the relevant folder.

You will probably also have to change the ./mkvfiles/*.mkv

Answer (score 0):

I think, more or less this can work for you:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in *.mkv *.mp4 *.wmv; do # add the extensions you want
  dir=$(echo "$f" | grep -o "S[0-9][0-9]E[0-9][0-9]")
  mkdir -p $dir
  mv $f $dir
done
```

If you want to run the script just once, you can copy the folder's paths into a file, let's call it `list`:

```
/path/to/seriesX
/path/to/seriesY
/path/to/seriesZ
```

And then in the "root" folder the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

mapfile -t array < list
for d in "${array[@]}"; do
  for f in "$d"/*.mkv; do
    dir="$(echo "$f" | grep -o "S[0-9][0-9]E[0-9][0-9]")"
    mkdir -p "$d"/"$dir"
    mv "$f" "$d"/"$dir"/
  done
done
```

Comment: This works, but creates directories of the form `S##E##`, while the OP wants directories of the form `E##`. Also, you may want to enclose `$f` in double quotes, to account for the case that the files have spaces in their filenames (in the OP's example they don't have, but you never know).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this from the directory where you have your files and empty directories, supposing that your files have an `.mkv` extension:

```
for file in *.mkv;do mv "$file" "$(echo $file | sed -E 's/.*S[0-9]+(E[0-9]+).*/\1/')";done
```

In the above `for` loop, `mv` is used to move each file (`"$file"`) to the respective episode directory (`"$(echo $file | sed -E 's/.*S[0-9]+(E[0-9]+).*/\1/')"`). Here, `sed` is used to extract the episode from the filename. Essentially, it matches the `S##E##` part of the filename using a regular expression (`.*S[0-9]+(E[0-9]+).*`), from which only the part inside the parentheses is kept (`\1` at the end of `sed` command).

Initial file structure:

```
.
├── E01
├── E02
├── E03
├── E04
├── E05
├── tv.show.2009.S01E01.episodename1.mkv
├── tv.show.2009.S01E02.episodename1.mkv
├── tv.show.2009.S01E03.episodename1.mkv
├── tv.show.2009.S01E04.episodename1.mkv
└── tv.show.2009.S01E05.episodename1.mkv
```

Result:

```
.
├── E01
│   └── tv.show.2009.S01E01.episodename1.mkv
├── E02
│   └── tv.show.2009.S01E02.episodename1.mkv
├── E03
│   └── tv.show.2009.S01E03.episodename1.mkv
├── E04
│   └── tv.show.2009.S01E04.episodename1.mkv
└── E05
    └── tv.show.2009.S01E05.episodename1.mkv
```

While you mention that you have already created the episode directories, you can create them and also move the files in them with a modification to the command above. The modification just adds `mkdir "$(echo $file | sed -E 's/.*S[0-9]+(E[0-9]+).*/\1/')"` to the command (the `echo` part is the same as in the `mv` before). Thus, the command to create the directories and move the files in them is:

```
for file in *.mkv;do mkdir "$(echo $file | sed -E 's/.*S[0-9]+(E[0-9]+).*/\1/')" && mv "$file" "$(echo $file | sed -E 's/.*S[0-9]+(E[0-9]+).*/\1/')";done
```

Initial file structure:

```
.
├── tv.show.2009.S01E01.episodename1.mkv
├── tv.show.2009.S01E02.episodename1.mkv
├── tv.show.2009.S01E03.episodename1.mkv
├── tv.show.2009.S01E04.episodename1.mkv
└── tv.show.2009.S01E05.episodename1.mkv
```

Result:

```
.
├── E01
│   └── tv.show.2009.S01E01.episodename1.mkv
├── E02
│   └── tv.show.2009.S01E02.episodename1.mkv
├── E03
│   └── tv.show.2009.S01E03.episodename1.mkv
├── E04
│   └── tv.show.2009.S01E04.episodename1.mkv
└── E05
    └── tv.show.2009.S01E05.episodename1.mkv
```